# Assistance debugging this logcat/ANR?

Tags: android, logcat

I've had a report of an application not responding in one of my apps, does anyone have any knowledge of this error? how to counter it?.

I cant see any reference of my activities or the location of the error, is it simply on their phone side?.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40028280 self=0xd170
| sysTid=436 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006432
at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:946)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread" prio=5 tid=48 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f38490 self=0x10fb870
| sysTid=11406 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=5729904
at android.hardware.SensorManager.sensors_data_poll(Native Method)
at android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread$SensorThreadRunnable.run(SensorManager.java:455)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"WifiWatchdogThread" prio=5 tid=78 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c72968 self=0x8d2918
| sysTid=18071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=577584
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at com.android.server.WifiWatchdogService$WifiWatchdogThread.run(WifiWatchdogService.java:983)

"DHCP Handler Thread" prio=5 tid=77 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40525a88 self=0xf75090
| sysTid=18034 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3340288
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"WifiMonitor" prio=5 tid=69 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d6f720 self=0x5afc10
| sysTid=18032 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7335184
at android.net.wifi.WifiNative.waitForEvent(Native Method)
at android.net.wifi.WifiMonitor$MonitorThread.run(WifiMonitor.java:270)

"Direct DHCP Handler Thread" prio=5 tid=79 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f4efe0 self=0x12ed2d0
| sysTid=30020 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6114672
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"DHCP Handler Thread" prio=5 tid=63 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ccc418 self=0x1145c50
| sysTid=29851 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=12177048
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"WifiMonitor" prio=5 tid=62 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4108a8c0 self=0x1162c38
| sysTid=29849 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7313424
at android.net.wifi.WifiNative.waitForEvent(Native Method)
at android.net.wifi.WifiMonitor$MonitorThread.run(WifiMonitor.java:270)

"Binder Thread #16" prio=5 tid=76 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b44898 self=0x628508
| sysTid=20266 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7111432
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #15" prio=5 tid=75 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a01b08 self=0x37d3e8
| sysTid=20213 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6346776
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:~3991)
- waiting to lock <0x4052cff8> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService) held by threadid=74 (Binder Thread #14)
at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:811)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1546)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #14" prio=5 tid=74 SUSPENDED
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d722f0 self=0x625d50
| sysTid=19897 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7046192
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ApplicationThreadNative.java:761)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.performReceiveLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:10957)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.deliverToRegisteredReceiverLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11022)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.processNextBroadcast(ActivityManagerService.java:11228)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:10772)
at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:355)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1546)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #13" prio=5 tid=73 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b3fde0 self=0x8a7068
| sysTid=19896 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=9080112
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #12" prio=5 tid=72 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40e27150 self=0x6ae230
| sysTid=19871 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2462160
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #11" prio=5 tid=71 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d8bac0 self=0x620d70
| sysTid=2011 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7022456
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #10" prio=5 tid=70 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ecd5f0 self=0x6b2610
| sysTid=2010 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7022032
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"loc_api" prio=5 tid=65 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d69ee8 self=0x6ab4b8
| sysTid=1377 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6992968
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"DrmEventService" prio=5 tid=68 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40bc64e8 self=0x690420
| sysTid=1118 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2463088
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"DrmManagerClient.EventHandler" prio=5 tid=67 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a76a28 self=0x27a028
| sysTid=1113 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6345432
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"DrmManagerClient.InfoHandler" prio=5 tid=66 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405dbd70 self=0x60d528
| sysTid=1112 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8226576
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"com.android.server.HDMIListener" prio=5 tid=64 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40aafa28 self=0x607588
| sysTid=828 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6507960
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:78)
at com.android.server.HDMIListener.listenToSocket(HDMIListener.java:151)
at com.android.server.HDMIListener.run(HDMIListener.java:195)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #9" prio=5 tid=61 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ace430 self=0x60daf0
| sysTid=788 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6280184
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=60 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ab9d70 self=0x295068
| sysTid=721 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2707872
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40ab9a38> (a java.lang.VMThread)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"GpsLocationProvider" prio=5 tid=59 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40aa5090 self=0x279380
| sysTid=665 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3012904
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at com.android.server.location.GpsLocationProvider$GpsLocationProviderThread.run(GpsLocationProvider.java:3093)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@40a9a838" daemon prio=5 tid=58 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a9d748 self=0x21ffc8
| sysTid=664 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2225096
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x407f7598> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue...
```

Comment: The app does not utilize, GPS or Sensors are any HTTP requests also.

Comment: That appears to be a thread dump of the system_server process.  You probably want to examine the thread dump of your app process, particularly the main thread, at the point of the ANR.

Comment: where is the point exactly the ANR occurred?

Answer (score 3):

As we can see, "Binder Thread #14" prio=5 tid=74 SUSPENDED", it is saying it is being suspended for one of the 2 reasons, either GC is running on this thread OR there is/was a debugger attached to this section of code. In either case, it was being suspended, not allowing it to resume,

Now while thread-74 is being suspended, there is one more thread "Binder Thread #15" prio=5 tid=75 MONITOR" in MONITOR state, waiting to acquire a lock over ActivityManagerService which is currently being held by a SUSPENDED thread-74.  waiting to lock <0x4052cff8> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService) held by threadid=74 (Binder Thread #14)

Thus a deadlock! So you might want to check if you are breaking the flow of code for debug purpose or the code might be doing some heavy object instantiations op causing GC.

Comment: But isn't ANR comes when main UI thread is stuck? Here two different non UI threads are in deadlock. Can it cause ANR for Main thread?